# Highcharts: To achieve exploded sections behaviour in Sunburst chart similar to pie charts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

Currently, pie chart has a property *sliced* that shows exploded section in pie chart.

Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/point/sliced/

However, Highcharts API reference does not show any property to support this behaviour in Sunburst chart.
I tried setting the data point sliced property in following example.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ng3bgckt/

```
 {
'id': '1.3',
'parent': '0.0',
'name': 'Asia',
'sliced': true
 },
```

The property sliced is set as true in the data point Asia, but it wasn't shown as exploded section.

Following are the examples of Sunburst chart with exploded sections:

Link 1: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/FlexChartWin/SunburstChart.html

Link 2: https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/getting-started-with-net-sunburst-chart-for-wpf-winforms-and-uwp

Is there any way in Highcharts to achieve the exploded sections behavior in Sunburst chart? Or if sliced and slicedOffset properties be made available for Sunburst chart?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

`sliced` option is now available in sunburst series.
API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.data.sliced

**OLD ANSWER:**

For now `sliced` option is not supported in sunburst series.

You can share the idea of adding this functionality to sunburst here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

or try to implement it on your own. This **live example** shows how to code the sliced mechanism for pyramid chart (for sunburst it can be done similarly + points hierarchy must be considered): http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/xpopxw1z/

```
 point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var translate = {
              translateX: this.graphic.translateX ? 0 : slicedOffset,
              translateY: 0
            }
            this.graphic.animate(translate);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: FWIW: this is now supported, see https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.data.sliced